# Android GridLayout with dynamic number of columns per row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

I have cards with different width and I would like to create a Grid Layout where width = match the parent (filling the screen) and fixed height.
I would like to set the cards in the Grid layout so the number of columns changes accordingly to the width of the elements that can fit the row.

So the elements will be set in a horizontal row till they can fit the screen and then go to the next row, with a vertical scroll when they exceed the fixed height.

I am trying to use a Grid Layout but I don't know if it the suitable solution for this.
I use **native Android**.

Here a picture of it should look like:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361905/how-to-add-elements-to-a-gridlayout-dynamically-with-different-column-widths-for

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [FlexboxLayoutManager](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

Add the following dependency to your build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0'
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

> LAYOUT.XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="250dp" />



</LinearLayout>
```

> ACTIVTY CODE

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.flexbox.FlexDirection;
import com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayoutManager;
import com.google.android.flexbox.JustifyContent;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    DataAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        initArray();
        FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.COLUMN);
        layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.FLEX_END);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new DataAdapter(this, arrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void initArray() {

        arrayList.add("ioreeoe");
        arrayList.add("fghfgh");
        arrayList.add("ftyjyjhghgh");
        arrayList.add("jfgewrg");
        arrayList.add("rwrewr");
        arrayList.add("ghyjtyfghh");
        arrayList.add("gfhfgh");
        arrayList.add("gfhfht");
        arrayList.add("retretret");
        arrayList.add("retret");
        arrayList.add("ioreeoe");
        arrayList.add("fghfgh");
        arrayList.add("ftyjyjhghgh");
        arrayList.add("jfgewrg");
        arrayList.add("rwrewr");
        arrayList.add("ghyjtyfghh");
        arrayList.add("gfhfgh");
        arrayList.add("gfhfht");
        arrayList.add("retretret");
        arrayList.add("retret");
        arrayList.add("ioreeoe");
        arrayList.add("fghfgh");
        arrayList.add("ftyjyjhghgh");
        arrayList.add("jfgewrg");
        arrayList.add("rwrewr");
        arrayList.add("ghyjtyfghh");
        arrayList.add("gfhfgh");
        arrayList.add("gfhfht");
        arrayList.add("retretret");
        arrayList.add("retret");
    }

}
```

> Adapter code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by nilesh on 3/4/18.
 */

public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public DataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.title.setText(arrayList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nilu);
        }
    }
}
```

> custom_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nilu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/test"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#050505" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> @drawable/test

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#d10e0e"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#070fe9" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

> **RESULT**

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I need. I just changed:
layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.FLEX_START);

Comment: The layout gets cut, if the view in recycler view is updated like Change of button color or text font

Comment: Unlike the picture in the original question, this has the FlexDirection set to COLUMN instead of ROW. Setting it to `FlexDirection.ROW` will make it match the original request.

Comment: @AskNilesh nice one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Staggered GridView libraries. For eg. https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid 
**Edit:**
add dependency in build.gradle and in your xml you can add:

```
 <com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView

        android:id="@+id/itemgridfragment_gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:column_count="2"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:item_margin="@dimen/fragment_landingpage_8" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried your solution and it was good but not exactly what I need. The reply of @Nilesh Rathod suit my need.
Thank you for your help, by the way it's an interesting solution.