# I want to make a RecyclerView with a dynamic width depending on the size of the text in it

Tags: android, android-fragments

Like this[image: Like this]

if there is no space for any item it is been shifted to next line

Comment: send me the link to check it out

Comment: You can not create a like this view in Recyclerview 
Follow this link 
https://github.com/nex3z/FlowLayout

Comment: If it can't be created in Recycler view then what u prefer ??

Comment: @HatimBaroodwala check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49973416/7666442

Comment: setLayoutManager
(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutManager)
in RecyclerView cannot be applied
to
(com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayoutManager)      <- Error while setting layout to recycler view  @NileshRathod

Comment: Flow layout is best option

Comment: @HatimBaroodwala follow link that i have added in my above comment i have added whole example how to use `FlexboxLayoutManager` with `Recyclerview`

Comment: @AravindV give me an example that how to use Flow Layout

Comment: @Hatim Baroodwala Try this one it will help's you https://github.com/nex3z/FlowLayout

Comment: It is solved by Migrating My Project to AndroidX. Thank you @NileshRathod

Comment: It is solved by Migrating My Project to AndroidX. Thank you @AravindV