# Multi Line RecyclerView In android How to achieve this type of view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I just stucked on this type of a view.
I am not able to understand how can i achieve this type of a view using `recyclerview` or `Chipgroup`.
If i am using `ChipGroup` then i have to Make it dynamic because data will come from rest Apis and if i go for `RecyclerView` then how can i make it multi line.

Any help Will appreciate.

[image: This Type Of View]

here What I Am getting, This Is i already developed
[image: What I Am getting]

Comment: I don't understand what problem are you facing? Just create this kind of shape for _rowItem.xml_ and use _GridLayoutManager_ for it

Comment: Check Another Image

Comment: Which another image? Here is only one image

Comment: check again above image

Comment: Which layout manager are you using for it?

Comment: @SandeepParish check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/49973244/7666442 using `FlexboxLayoutManager`

Comment: @NileshRathod i Already checked it and integrated but issue is how can i make it in horizontal scroll with multiple line?

Comment: have you checked staggered layoutmanager?

Comment: Yes I checked that and chipGroup also

Comment: @SandeepParish https://github.com/BelooS/ChipsLayoutManager

Comment: https://github.com/robertlevonyan/materialChipView

Comment: @NileshRathod I already tried this If i use it as vertical then it non scrollable and in horizontal it is showing more then 2 lines but i want it in only 2 lines.

Comment: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout/issues/215