# Android FlexBox Layout shows only fixed number of lines

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite, android-gridlayout, android-flexboxlayout

I'm trying to build a word-to-word RTL language ebook application. The data for the ebook is stored in an Sqlite database. After vigorous searching I found Flexbox layout suitable to my need in order to display my data in my required format. The following link helped me out: [Android GridLayout with dynamic number of columns per row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49973244/android-gridlayout-with-dynamic-number-of-columns-per-row.) But the issue is that if the data passed in the view is large, then partial data is being displayed. If the data passed is small, then i have no issues at all.

Here is the adapter code:

```
public class VerseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VerseAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<verseItem> items;
private Context context;
wordsAdapter sAdapter;
GridLayoutManager layoutManager;

public VerseAdapter(List<verseItem> items, Context context) {
    this.items = items;
    this.context = context;
}


// This method is used to attach
// custom layout to the recycler view
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View vw = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.verse_row, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(vw);
}


// This method is used to set the action
// to the widgets of our custom layout.
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    verseItem item = items.get(position);
    ArrayList<wordsModel> models = new ArrayList<>(item.getWordsModelList());
    String ayahnum = "" + item.getAyah();
    holder.ayah.setText(ayahnum);

    holder.verses_telugu.setText(item.getVerses_telugu());
    
    // FlexboxLayoutManager code:
    FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(context);
    layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW_REVERSE);
    layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.FLEX_START);
    ViewHolder.wordsrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    sAdapter = new wordsAdapter(models);
    ViewHolder.wordsrecyclerView.setAdapter(sAdapter);
    sAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);

    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView ayah;
    TextView verses_telugu;
    public static RecyclerView wordsrecyclerView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ayah = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ayah);
        verses_telugu = itemView.findViewById(R.id.telugu_line);
        wordsrecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.words_RV_id);

    }
 }

}
```

Here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/ayah"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
         android:layout_margin="5dp"
         android:textAlignment="viewStart"
         android:textColor="#27A82C"
         android:textSize="18sp"
         android:textStyle="bold" />

   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/words_RV_id"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/telugu_line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how the final result show actually look like:

[image: Screenshot1]

This is how my app looks like:

[image: Screenshot2(Part1)]

[image: Screenshot2(Part1)]

Now if you notice from the screenshots, the data that i'm trying to display is same. But in my app, not all words are being displayed as you can notice.

Another thing i have noticed is for larger data if the screen orientation is vertical the maximum lines i can see is 10 and if it is horizontal i can see 6 lines at max. These number of lines are fixed for all the places where the data is large. If the data is smaller it is displayed in the exact number of lines required and as mentioned earlier I have no issues at all.

Hoping someone helps me out soon. Thanks in advance. (: