# is it possible to set RecyclerView use GirdLayoutManager with dynamic column?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i don't know how to describe it, it like.

[image]

**I really appreciate your help and have a nice day!**

Comment: Did you consider using Material Chips? https://material.io/components/chips/android#using-chips

Comment: I dont think that is what i want but thanks so much

Comment: @LộcTrầnPhước Please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69405744/improve-spacing-between-recycleview-items/69406537#69406537

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this for dynamic span count.

Implementation is taken from a Fragment.

https://gist.github.com/mtsahakis/33085460b9707fdf0729

```
 private var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView? = null

@Nullable
fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view, container, false)
    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)
    // ommiting other recycler view set up, such as adapter and Layout manager set up ..
    val viewTreeObserver: ViewTreeObserver = mRecyclerView!!.viewTreeObserver
    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
        calculateSize() }
}

private val sColumnWidth = 120 // assume cell width of 120dp

private fun calculateSize() {
    val spanCount =
        Math.floor((mRecyclerView!!.width / convertDPToPixels(sColumnWidth)).toDouble())
            .toInt()
    (mRecyclerView!!.layoutManager as GridLayoutManager?)!!.spanCount =
        spanCount
}

private fun convertDPToPixels(dp: Int): Float {
    val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics)
    val logicalDensity: Float = metrics.density
    return dp * logicalDensity
}
```

Comment: Adding a short sample code to your answer would be recommended.

Comment: I have added the snippet as well now.

Comment: I'll try. Thanks so much.i 'll reponse in tomorrow cause i'm so tired.